# SQL Query Between with or

Tags: php, mysql, sql, between

well i have a table in mysql that i want to get the data between a date range but when a execute this query:

```
select * from cartap c inner join rastreo r on (c.idCartaporte=r.idcartap) 
inner join contratistas ct on (ct.NoContrato=c.NumeroContrato) inner join datosfiscales df 
on (ct.DatosFiscales_ClaveUnicaDF=df.ClaveUnicaDF) where creationdate between '$begdate' 
and '$enddate' and idper ='2001' or idper ='2002' and 
estadopago like '%$estadocp%' and estadoliquidacion like '%$estadoliq%' order by $order
```

i get data out of that range, i know is because of the OR condition because it gives me the correct idper values but return values from dates out of the range and i need to use that or something similar because what i want to get is a report between two dates and apply a filter for two (or more) clients (that is the idper) but between those dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to understand the rules of boolean conditions.  So, I would recommend in general that you always use parentheses when your conditions mix `and`s and `or`s.  They are like training wheels.

In your case, though, `in` fixes the issue:

```
where creationdate between '$begdate' and '$enddate' and
      idper in ('2001', '2002') and 
      estadopago like '%$estadocp%' and 
      estadoliquidacion like '%$estadoliq%'
```

And you should learn to use parameters so your code is not subject to unexpected syntax errors and SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks that worked fine, and i'll take note from that thank you